# Ignore logging of duplicated exception messages of third party libs

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, slf4j, logback

I need to handle duplication of specific exeptions in my logs.

I use slf4j and logback for logging in my application. I use some external services(DB, apache kafka, third-party libs, etc.). When connection was lost to such service I got exception, such as

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.a.kafka.common.network.Selector - Error in I/O with localhost/127.0.0.1
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:238) ~[kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

The problem is that I got this message every second. This exception message will flood my log file, so I'll have a few GBs in log file in N hours.

**I want to have log message about this exception once per 1-5 minutes. Is there any way to ignore duplication of exceptions in log file?**

*Possible solutions:*

1. Ignore all logs for specific package and class.
   [bad, beucase I can skip important message]
2. Use http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#DuplicateMessageFilter
   [bad, because I can set only properties AllowedRepetitions or CacheSize. It'll match to all messages, but I need only specific exeption]
3. Write custom filter
   Maybe, you know already imlemented solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy to write new turbo filter and implement any logic to reject some specific logging.

I've ilemented new filter with next configuration
**logback.xml**

```
<turboFilter class="package.DuplicationTimeoutTurboFilter">
    <MinutesToBlock>3</MinutesToBlock>
    <KeyPattern>
        <loggerClass>org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector</loggerClass>
        <message>java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information</message>
    </KeyPattern>
</turboFilter>
```

and implementation:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.TurboFilter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;
import org.slf4j.Marker;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DuplicationTimeoutTurboFilter extends TurboFilter {

    private static final int CLEAN_UP_THRESHOLD = 1000;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<KeyPattern, LocalDateTime> recentlyMatchedPatterns = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private Set<KeyPattern> ignoringPatterns = new HashSet<>();

    private long minutesToBlock = 3L;

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(Marker marker, Logger logger, Level level, String format, Object[] params, Throwable t) {
        String rawLogMessage = format + Arrays.toString(params) + Objects.toString(t);  //sometimes throwable can be inserted into params argument

        Set<KeyPattern> matchedIgnoringSet = ignoringPatterns.stream()
                .filter(key -> match(key, logger, rawLogMessage))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        if (!matchedIgnoringSet.isEmpty() && isLoggedRecently(matchedIgnoringSet)) {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        }

        return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
    }

    private boolean match(KeyPattern keyPattern, Logger logger, String rawText) {
        String loggerClass = keyPattern.getLoggerClass();
        String messagePattern = keyPattern.getMessage();
        return loggerClass.equals(logger.getName()) && rawText.contains(messagePattern);
    }

    private boolean isLoggedRecently(Set<KeyPattern> matchedIgnoredList) {
        for (KeyPattern pattern : matchedIgnoredList) {
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

            LocalDateTime lastLogTime = recentlyMatchedPatterns.putIfAbsent(pattern, now);
            if (lastLogTime == null) {
                return false;
            }

            LocalDateTime blockedTillTime = lastLogTime.plusMinutes(minutesToBlock);
            if (blockedTillTime.isAfter(now)) {
                return true;
            } else if (blockedTillTime.isBefore(now)) {
                recentlyMatchedPatterns.put(pattern, now);
                cleanupIfNeeded();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void cleanupIfNeeded() {
        if (recentlyMatchedPatterns.size() > CLEAN_UP_THRESHOLD) {
            LocalDateTime oldTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(minutesToBlock * 2);
            recentlyMatchedPatterns.values().removeIf(lastLogTime -> lastLogTime.isAfter(oldTime));
        }
    }

    public long getMinutesToBlock() {
        return minutesToBlock;
    }

    public void setMinutesToBlock(long minutesToBlock) {
        this.minutesToBlock = minutesToBlock;
    }

    public void addKeyPattern(KeyPattern keyPattern) {
        ignoringPatterns.add(keyPattern);
    }

    public static class KeyPattern {
        private String loggerClass;
        private String message;

        //constructor, getters, setters, equals, hashcode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is simply extending the [DuplicateMessageFilter](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/DuplicateMessageFilter.html) you already found. It is not final and it is fairly easy to:

1. implement a new TurboFilter with a filter method based on classname or exceptionType or anything else you want to make your initial decision based upon
2. then delegate to the parent class for duplicity-check

The parameters you have available:

```
public FilterReply decide(Marker marker, Logger logger, Level level,
  String format, Object[] params, Throwable t) {
```

Include both `Throwable` and `Logger`.